# A real world problem I have encountered in my work (Not a book!) - opcode allocation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

"here's a word size, here is a list of data bits of an instruction, and their relative frequencies, allocate them as best you can"

Tags were a guess, sorry.

I find this problem to be VERY interesting, I'm not sure what I expect as an answer but I want at the very least to share it.

### **Terminology**

---

A **bit** is a **binary digit**, a 0 or a 1.

A **word** is a collection of **bits** (for this application 8 of them, this may be called a **byte** or sometimes **char**)

An **instruction** is a number of words such that **the first m bits unambiguously identify the instruction** (there will be examples), the remaining bits may be data or ignored.

A **register** is a number of words "inside the machine" that instructions can operate on and use data from. (there will always be at least 4 registers, due to the four colour theorem)

A **subregister** is a continuous partition of a register and is a number of words in length.

The **memory** is a strip of words starting at 0 to some finite limit.

The **size** of a register is what subregister we wish to use

A **general purpose** register is a register used for manipulating data, not the flow of the program or manipulating structures of the program (eg stack)

### **Examples to understand terminology**

---

### **x86_64 registers**

This is a real world example, in the CPU of the computer you are reading this on is a register called "a", it is 64 bits (8 bytes) long.
`rax` address the full 64 bits, `eax` addresses the lower 32 bits, `ax` the lower 16, `al` the lower 8 and `ah` the upper 8 of `ax`, as a diagram:

```
                      register a (the numbers below are bytes)
|   7   |   6   |   5   |   4   |   3   |   2   |   1   |   0   |
|                          rax                                  |
                                |               eax             |
                                                |      ax       |
                                                |  ah   |  al   |
```

So `al` is a subregister of `ax`.

### **Instructions**

Suppose I want to move the contents of register `X` into register `Y`, we denote this by the **assembly** instruction:

`MOV X,Y`, we move into X the value of Y.

However using `a` and `b` registers from the **_x86** example above:

`MOV a,b` means copy the contents of b into a, but what parts of b and a?

`MOV rax,rbx` makes sense, clearly this means copy the 64 bits of b into a.

`MOV eax,ebx` means copy the lowest 32 bits of b into a.

Clearly the **sizes** must be the same for the `MOV` instruction.

### **Defining an instruction**

Suppose we have 4 registers, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. Suppose also we have 4 sizes, 64 bits, lower 32, lower 16 and lower 8.

we may express a register as 2 bits, (`00` `01` `10` and `11` respectively)

We may also express a size as 2 bits (the same as above respectively)

So `MOV GP,GP` where "GP" means "general purpose register" has **6 bits** of data, target register, source register and size.

Recall that an instruction is a number of words, this means (I will use word size as 8 in all examples) to fit in one word the first 2 bits must uniquely and unambiguously define MOV. If we can't do this then we must use 16 bits (2 words) and this means 8 bits are ignored. **this is inefficient and what is to be minimised**

### **Worked example problem**

Suppose we have the following **instruction set**

`MOV GP,GP` - Copy the contents of the second register into the first.

`MOV [GP],GP` - Copy the value of the second register into the memory location given by the first. (**example** `MOV [rax],ebx` sets the memory location `rax` to the first byte of of `ebx`, the memory location `rax+1` to the second byte of `ebx`, all the way to `rax+3` being the final byte of the 4 byte register ebx.) This requires 2 registers and a size (it must be `[rax]` for this machine in the example because a memory address is 64 bits, the amount of data to copy into memory is given purely by the right hand register)

`MOV GP,[GP]` - Copy the value of the memory location given by the second register into the first register (**example** `MOV ax,[rdx]` means copy the memory value at `rdx` to the lower byte of `a` and copy the memory value at `rdx+1` to the second lowest byte of `a`)

`HALT` - this signals the end of the program and shuts down the machine (it doesn't execute any more instructions after this)

`NOP` - short for no op, it literally means do nothing. This is what your processor does when idle.

### **A naive attempt**

`MOV GP,GP` has 6 bits of data

`MOV [GP],GP` has 6 bits of data

`MOV GP,[GP]` has 6 bits of data

`HALT` has 0 bits of data

`NOP` has 0 bits of data

Let us also consider an `instruction frequency`, higher indicates more frequent and lower indicates less frequent, is is simply a ranking (an integer value).

Clearly the first 3 will be very common instructions and the last 2 will be very uncommon, it makes sense to allocate them like so:

```
MOV a,b   -->  00aabbss (ss is size)
MOV [a],b -->  01aabbss 
MOV a,[b] -->  10aabbss
HALT      -->  1100xxxx (x = ignored)
NOP       -->  1101xxxx 
(unused)  -->  1110
(unused)  -->  111100
(unused)  -->  111101
```

You can see the pattern forming I hope, you'll also note this is unambiguous, if one were to allocate binary numbers for these you will note `HALT` would be `100vwxyz` (4) (where HALT would ignore vwxyz) However this would be interpreted as `MOV into register 0v the yz sized block of data starting at the location in memory given by register wx`

Hence my simple pattern. The above example was simple to solve regardless.

### **Where it becomes complex**

Suppose we have some more instructions:

`ADD GP,GP` - Add to the LHS register the contents of the RHS register (6 bits of data, a lower frequency than any MOV, 2 registers and a size)

`INC GP` - increment register by 1 (4 bits of data, register and size)

`DEC GP` - like `INC` but decreases a register's value by 1 (4 bits of data)

`SET GP,mask,value` - mask and value are 8 bits each, for each `1` in the mask set the corresponding byte in GP to the 8 bits given in value. so `SET GP,11111111,00000000` sets an entire register to 0 - 18 bits of data (2+8+8)

`MUL GP,GP` - Another 6 data bit, same format as `ADD`

`NEG GP` - negates the integer value of GP (4 data bits)

`PUSH GP` - 4 data bits, register and size

`POP GP` - 4 data bits, register and size

You can see that the moment we have more than 3 things with the same amount of data something has to spill and it might displace something else.

My question is, what is the best way to allocate a set of operations?

This boils down (hopefully now you see how/why) "How can I create a word length * n string of binary digits that uniquely defines an operation with n data bits where the least number of bits are ignored and equally eligible operations are ranked based on their relative frequency."

At first glance this appears VERY similar to box packing, and it almost is, the constraint of minimising the number of words for an instruction is important however.

One of my earliest attempts was to put this in a spreadsheet and order by data bits, this works for instructions that want to share the same instruction length, but can unfairly place (for example) the `SET` instruction last, even though it'd nicely fit in a 24 bit (3 byte) instruction. There is more to this problem than meats the eye, I want to study this!

I wont bother giving you a full instruction set because it doesn't matter to the problem it boils down to "here's a word size, here is a list of data bits of an instruction, and their relative frequencies, allocate them as best you can" - This question would have made little sense without the above.

Comment: Don't keep telling us "this problem is interesting." I realize you are trying to encourage people read a long problem, but you don't have to apply the hard sell.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews fixed